# Stackexchange Redis - How to get large number of records paged

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Is there a way to get the results paged. I'm using

```
 Database.HashGetAll(GetKey(key));
```

from the [Stackexchange.Redis .Net Client](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) but it throws OutOfMemory exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HashScan` method to iterate over a redis hash.

As you iterate through the result set, StackExchange.Redis will automatically call `HSCAN` to return more pages of results as required. You can optionally use the `pageSize` parameter to influence the number of records returned by each call to `HSCAN`.

```
var hashEntries = database.HashScan(key);

foreach (var entry in hashEntries)
{
    // ...
}
```

At any point during the iteration you can get the current value of the cursor, which would allow you to start a new iteration from the same page of results.

```
((IScanningCursor) hashEntries).Cursor
```

Have a look at http://redis.io/commands/scan for more details about how it works under the hood.

> #### Number of elements returned at every SCAN call
>
> SCAN family functions do not guarantee that the number of elements
> returned per call are in a given range. The commands are also allowed
> to return zero elements, and the client should not consider the
> iteration complete as long as the returned cursor is not zero.
>
> #### The COUNT option
>
> While SCAN does not provide guarantees about the number of elements returned at every iteration, it is possible to
> empirically adjust the behavior of SCAN using the COUNT option.
> Basically with COUNT the user specified the amount of work that should
> be done at every call in order to retrieve elements from the
> collection. This is just an hint for the implementation, however
> generally speaking this is what you could expect most of the times
> from the implementation.
>
> - The default COUNT value is 10.
> - When iterating the key space, or a Set, Hash or Sorted Set that is big enough to be represented by a hash table, assuming no MATCH option
>   is used, the server will usually return count or a bit more than count
>   elements per call.

Comment: The concept of `HashScan()` is confusing and regardless of all the existing documentation, still poorly understood and overly complex. I did a test. I populated 1164 entries to a hash, and ran a `hashEntries = database.HashScan(key, "*", 50)`. The suggested, doing `foreach (var entry in hashEntries)` will iterate the ENTIRE hash of 1164 entries on a single pass. During iteration, a new cursor will be issued after my requested 50 entries, if I choose to stop iterating and continue later. As I didn't the issue became very simple: 1) HashScan(), 2) iterate, 3) done!